# Mobile Safari - Form Submit, go back, then on resubmit it refreshes page

Tags: html, forms, safari, submit, reload

I have an HTML Form where users can select filters and submit the request for a list based on those filters.  On mobile safari only if the user goes back and tries to resubmit the form based on the same or different filters, it just refreshes the page.  Here's the form code... I added the onclick because initially it didn't reload but just did nothing.

```
<form method="get" id="gamefilterform">
<select name="gametype[]" multiple>
<option value="0" style="visibility:hidden" label="NULL"></option>
<option value="1" selected="selected" label="team">Team</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected" label="head_to_head">Head to Head</option>
</select>
<select name="gamediff[]" multiple>
<option value="0" style="visibility:hidden" label="NULL"></option>
<option value="1" selected="selected" label="easy">Easy</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected" label="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected" label="hard">Hard</option>
</select>
<input name="list" type="submit" value="List" formaction="games/list.php" onclick="document.getElementById('gamefilterform').submit()">
<input name="random" type="submit" value="Random" formaction="games/random.php" onclick="document.getElementById('gamefilterform').submit()">
</form>
```